# TextField inside a table

Tags: tables, hyperref, forms

I'm trying to create a page which will be printed and signed by two different people. On this page I want to have a textfield where you can write your name prior to printing the page.

My problem is the following: The textfield works well enough, except that the cline underneath the textfield is erased when enetering something in the textfield (while using Adobe Reader). I've tried to compensate for this but that only works for one out of the two textfields. How do I make it so that no line under my textfield is erased?

MWE

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

    \usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks={false}, linkcolor={black}, urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

    \newcommand\B{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}  % <-- Saw this somewhere as a fix, but only corrects the one column in the table below.

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ p{0.30\linewidth}  p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.30\linewidth}}
      \begin{center}\textbf{Me}\end{center} & & \begin{center}\textbf{Them}\end{center} \\
       &  &  \\
       &  &  \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Sign.}} &  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Sign.}}\\
       &  & \\ 
      \TextField[bordercolor=, name=signMe]{}&  & \TextField[bordercolor=,name=signThem]{} \B \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} % <--- Here's the attempted fix inserted.
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Printed name}}&  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Printed name}} \\
       &  & \\
       &  &  \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Place and date}} &  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Place and date}}\\
    \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following fix:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

    \usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks={false}, linkcolor={black}, urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ p{0.30\linewidth}  p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.30\linewidth}}
      \begin{center}\textbf{Me}\end{center} & & \begin{center}\textbf{Them}\end{center} \\
       &  &  \\
       &  &  \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Sign.}} &  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Sign.}}\\
       &  & \\ 
      \TextField[bordercolor=, name=signMe]{}  &  & \TextField[bordercolor=,name=signThem]{}  \\
       &  &\\[-11pt] % <--- Here's the attempted fix inserted
      \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} 
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Printed name}}&  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Printed name}} \\
       &  & \\
       &  &  \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
      \footnotesize{\textbf{Place and date}} &  & \footnotesize{\textbf{Place and date}}\\
    \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
```